# The set $\mathcal{B}=\{[a,b] : a \in \Bbb Q, b \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q\}$ is a basis for $\tau$ on $\Bbb R$. Is $(\Bbb R, \tau)$ is regular?

Tags: general-topology

> The set $\mathcal{B}=\{[a,b] : a \in \Bbb Q, b \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q\}$ is a basis for some topology $\tau$ on $\Bbb R$. Figure out wheter $(\Bbb R, \tau)$ is regular.

$(\Bbb R, \tau)$ is regular if for any closed $F\subset \Bbb R$ and $x \in \Bbb R \setminus F$ there exists a neighborhood $U_F$ of $F$ and $U_x$ of $x$ for which $U_F \cap U_x = \emptyset$.

How do closed set look here? For any basic open set $[a,b]$ the complement is $(-\infty,a) \cup (b, \infty)$ so the closed sets are intersection of these sets?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all closed sets are intersections of such sets. You have to have in mind that the intersection of empty family of sets is $\Bbb R$.

However, I wouldn't go this way. It's better to use the other characterisation of regularity. Namely the space is regular if for any $x\in\Bbb R$ and $B\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in  B$ there is $B'\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in  B'\subset \overline{B'}\subset B$.

Now it sufficies to prove this characterisation of regularity and to verify if this condition is satisfied.